# Using Dockerhub Regex for Autobuilds

Tags: regex, docker, dockerhub

Whenever I try to use regex for a branch name in an autobuild, I get the message that the branch is not found. I'm trying to match "dev2/FIRE-" exactly and then anything else after that. What is the regex that I would use to match this?

I've added a screenshot formatted how Dockerhub wants it, but the branch name regex is incorrect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: An attempt I made within DockerHub]

Comment: try this: ‍`/^dev2\/(FIRE-).*`

Comment: Still getting the branch not found :/ I'm still not sure why

Comment: I missed a `/`. try this `/^dev2\/(FIRE-).*/` hope it work.

Comment: No luck :/ with this new regex, it won't even allow me to try to build, there's no option to trigger so it won't even tell me if the branch is now found. Your regex looks right, I don't know what the problem is